# bootstrap 4 multi level dropdown menu - second level first hide then shows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a menu item like in this example. The first level of dropdown menu is working correct, but the second level with this jquery code it is not good. You can view that if you click on the Menu4.4 then first it hides the menu and shows again (like blinking one). How can I make a workaround or correct this behaviour?

```js
$(function() {
  "use strict";
  // dropdown slide in navigation
  $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function() {
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });
  // dropdown slide in navigation
  $(".dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function() {
    $(this).find(".dropdown-menu").first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav li .nav-link {
  padding-right: .5rem;
  padding-left: .5rem;
}

#navbarCollapse li.active {
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse li.active a {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse .menu {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#navbarCollapse .dropdown-menu {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#navbarCollapse li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
  color: #BA122B;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
  transform: perspective(1px) translateZ(0);
}

#navbarCollapse li a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

#navbarCollapse parent:after {}

.body {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.off-canvas-active .off-canvas-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.off-canvas-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  z-index: 1000;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.offcanvas-collapse.open {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: slide-right .3s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide-right {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

.offcanvas-collapse {
  position: fixed;

  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 330px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  transition-property: width;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.navbar-expand-md .navbar-toggler {
  display: block!important;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  background-color: #BA122B;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler .icon-bar {
  background: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(2px, 2px);
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(2) {
  opacity: 0;
}

.navbar-toggler .icon-bar:nth-of-type(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(1px, -1px);
}

.navbar-toggler.collapsed .icon-bar {
  margin: 5px auto;
  transform: none;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="offcanvas-collapse navbar open" id="navbarCollapse">
  <div class="menu-body bg-white open" style="left: 1267.5px;">
    <ul class="nav menu navbar-nav ml-auto text-uppercase mod-list">
      <li class="item-103 default current active"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home!</a></li>
      <li class="item-111"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu1</a></li>
      <li class="item-104 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu2</a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
          <li class="item-105"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu2.1</a></li>
          <li class="item-106"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu2.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-112 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu3</a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
          <li class="item-114"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu3.1</a></li>
          <li class="item-115"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu3.2</a></li>
          <li class="item-116"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu3.3</a></li>
          <li class="item-117"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu3.4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-118 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu4</a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
          <li class="item-119"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu4.1</a></li>
          <li class="item-142"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu4.2</a></li>
          <li class="item-143"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu4.3</a></li>
          <li class="item-154 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dep dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu4.4</a>
            <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
              <li class="item-155"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu4.4.1</a></li>
              <li class="item-156"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu4.4.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="item-157"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu4.5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-137 deeper parent dropdown"><a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Menu5</a>
        <ul class="nav-child unstyled small dropdown-menu">
          <li class="item-138"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu5.1</a></li>
          <li class="item-139"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu5.2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item-140"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Menu6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```